# Replace all values (all the columns) in a dataframe based on a condition using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this (but really big):

```
      1234  4567   7890
Ecu    0.2     0     12         
Per    0.8    12      0  
Col    345    -3      0
```

I need to replace the numbers in all the columns (but not on the first one) with the condition `if X > 0, X = 1  and if X < 0, X = 0` and a result I need another dataframe as follows.

```
      1234  4567   7890
Ecu      1     0      1         
Per      1     1      0  
Col      1     0      0
```

Comment: What value would you like to have if `x == 0`?

Comment: if X < 0, X == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boolean indexing:

```
In [7]: df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].gt(0).astype(np.uint8)

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
      1234  4567  7890
Ecu    0.2     0     1
Per    0.8     1     0
Col  345.0     0     0
```

It'll replace all positive numbers (`>0`) with `1` and all non-positive (`<=0`) with `0`